# Retrieve NSDate from CoreData and set it to an NSDate variable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdate

I'm trying to store an NSDate in CoreData and then retrieve it and apply it to a variable

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonTimer1: UIButton! {
        setTimersDate.zero = NSDate()
        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        var buttonTimer1Date = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("TimerDates", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
        buttonTimer1Date.setValue(setTimersDate.zero, forKey: "dates")

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Dates saving error")
        }
}

@IBOutlet weak var setTimer1: UIButton! {
        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate //Import Appdelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TimerDates")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        do {
            print(request[0].buttonTimer1Date)
        } catch {
            print("Cannot request data")
        }
}
```

This saves and prints the current date on the console, so I know the date is being stored. However, I want to set `request[0]` back to an NSDate().

Is this possible, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the fetch request

```
  let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate //Import Appdelegate
  let context = appDel.managedObjectContext
  let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TimerDates")

  do {
      let allDates = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [NSManagedObject]
      if !allDates.isEmpty { print(allDates[0].valueForKey("dates") }
  } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Cannot request data", error)
  }
```

However this code as a closure of an `IBOutlet` is a bit weird.

Comment: Thank you very much - I'll try that solution! It's actually called from `viewDidLoad()`, I thought putting it under a IBOutlet showed what I was trying to achieve more clearly. As a relative newby, I was probably wrong. I'll post my code exactly in future.